# How to run a function for every element with different results?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this nice script, by Bitwise Creative, to change the color of a numeric content by the value.

```
$(function () {
    // Score Color
    var score = parseInt($('em').text().trim());
    var color = 'red';
    if (!isNaN(score)) {
        if (score >= 2) {
            color = 'orange';
        }
        if (score >= 3) {
            color = 'green';
        }
        $('em').css('color', color);
    }
});
```

**My Problem:**
It change all numeric content with the same color. So if I have more than one numeric content, this script makes no different between the numbers and colors. How can I modify it like the way, that for example every [em] value [/em] becomes his own color?

```
<em>1</em> --> red
<em>2.5</em> --> orange
<em>3</em> --> green
<em>1.5</em> --> red
```

aso.

Comment: @Rajesh - that's **not** the issue. The issue is there's no loop in the code, so of course ALL the `em` get one colour

Comment: @Rajesh OP was already doing `parseInt` so string was not the issue.

Comment: Thanks dudes 4 support! Now I see my fail ...

Comment: @gurvinder372 Yup! Misread the question. My Bad!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('em').text()` will give you a string containing the combined text of all matched elements.

You need to iterate the `em` elements and apply the color to them individually

```
$(function () {
    // Score Color
    $( "em" ).each( function(){
        var score = parseInt($(this).text().trim());
        var color = 'red';
        if (!isNaN(score)) {
            if (score >= 2) {
                color = 'orange';
             }
             if (score >= 3) {
                 color = 'green';
             }
             $(this).css('color', color);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This works perfect for me, thank you very much! I have tried something with "each" but now I see what I´ve done wrong ;)

Answer (score 0):

if you want that if score is 2.5 then color must be orange
then given score must be `float` number and you can convert string to float number by using `parseFloat`
 which can be done by

```
var score = parseFloat($('em').text().trim());
```

Comment: Thank you too - also an interesting way!

Answer (score 0):

You could declare an `Object` to map integer values to corresponding colors.

```
var couleurs = {
  1: 'red',
  [2.5] : 'orange'
}
```

so that you can access as

```
$(this).css('color', couleurs[color]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To easy: just use a loop to iterate over all ems:

```
$('em').each( function(){
   var score = parseInt( $(this).text().trim() ),
          color = 'red';

   if (!isNaN(score)) return;

   if (score >= 2) {
        color = 'orange';
   }
   if (score >= 3) {
        color = 'green';
   }
    $(this).css('color', color);
});
```